how do i change the tab opacity/transparency of non-used tabs in edge
I just switched from google chrome to edge. I want the icons of the tabs i'm not currently on to NOT appear transparent. I dont want to change any other theming.
the other sites dont pop out at me when they are dimmed/faded like this. very annoying.

edit: thanks for answer @Reddy-lutonadio


I think this is due to Settings -> System and Performance -> Fade sleeping tabs being on. Try switching it off.

Technically, I commented and didn't answer. Did the suggestion work?
